# Split arduino run mode depending on active USB connection

Tags: usb

Ok, so i have a unit that i want to add information to the EEPROM, using the USB port, such as SSID for wifi shields.

Then i want to disconnect the USB cable, plugin a battery and then it should run its normal loop.

So something like:

```
IF usb-cable 
   run_setup_loop();
ELSE
   run_main_loop();
```

Comment: Which board do you use?

Comment: Uno 3 and Nano China

Comment: Not really possible with the Uno or Nano. The UNO might work if you change the program on the 16u2 (that does the usb to serial). I think it would be easier to detect serial input (e.g. user presses enter) using `if( Serial.available())`. And then when some serial data has come in, change "mode" to setup-mode.

Comment: The wifi module is serial also so that wouldnt work.